# Add a sort to a type using ML functions from Pure

Tags: isabelle, ml

I'm trying to define a new type definition command for Isabelle from FOL. This new type `"T"` should have the sort `"T::term"`, but I don't find any function to do so in Pure.

I have followed the ideas from `typedef.ML` from HOL.

Without this sort (the default sort) I don't get unification of sorts between the axioms I'm defining.